# Display current category without an active link in wp_list_categories

Tags: css, categories

I appreciate your time in looking into this for me.

I'm using `wp_list_categories` tag to display a list of categories in my navigation menu and I'd like to disable the link to the current category when viewing said category page.

My main reason is that the color attribute in my CSS style for `li.cat-item a` is overriding the color attribute for my CSS style for `.current-category a` and blocking my attempts to create a contrasting text color for the current category item.

Comment: I was able to disable the link by adding `pointer-events: none; cursor: default;` to `.current-category a` and then I solved the link color override by simply adding `li` to `.current-category a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_the_category();` to display your category in menu

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $separator = ' ';
    $output = '';
    if($categories){
        foreach($categories as $category) {

    $output .= '<a " href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
        }
    echo trim($output, $separator);
    }
?>
```

I used the `<a>` tag you can remove it for link. I Hope it help you